# How do you get to Denali National Park from Anchorage via bus?

Tags: usa, public-transport, buses, alaska

I will be travelling to **Anchorage** from **India** during **May-June**. I want to visit the **Denali National Park**.

I have seen that there is a train, but given the fact that I will reach Anchorage at 8PM local time, I don't think that is possible.

**Is there anyway via bus ?**

Could anyone share what the schedules are like ?

Comment: There seems to be a bus, but like the train, it has an early departure time. https://www.alaskatravel.com/park-connection-bus/