# Places to stay inside Denali National Park for easy access to the green bus service

Tags: usa, national-parks, alaska

Related to : [How do you get to Denali National Park from Anchorage via bus?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/186275/how-do-you-get-to-denali-national-park-from-anchorage-via-bus)

Is there any place to stay inside the Denali National Park where I can get easy access to the Green bus Service for the 8 hour tour ?

I will not be having access to a rental car as I am an international traveler without a license.